# YamlDotNet : Order serialized properties based on inheritance depth

Tags: c#, yamldotnet

In a tool project, I generate meta files for Unity3D assets. As all unity asset meta start with the same properties, I created a base type :

`public class MetaBase {
    public int fileFormatVersion { get; set; }
    public Guid guid { get; set; }
    public long timeCreated { get; set; }
    public string licenseType { get; set; }
}`

Serializing an instance of a type inheriting from *MetaBase* generates a file that unity accepts, but the fileFormatVersion, guid, timeCreated and licenseType are written at the bottom of the file whereas Unity writes them at the top. As I said, it works, but whenever Unity decides to overwrite the meta file, it generates some differences that need to be committed on my project repository, and I would prefer to avoid that if possible.

So, my first idea (after upgrading to YamlDotNet 4.0.0) was to add a *TypeInspectorSkeleton* which would sort the _IPropertyDescriptor_s depending on the declaring types of the property. But the *IPropertyDescriptor* does not provide access to the actual *Property*, nor does it provide access to its *baseDescriptor* property (for *PropertyDescriptor*/*OverridePropertyDescriptor*).

Shouldn't there be some way to access a Property owner type ? Or maybe there is a better may to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: Are you talking about .NET properties which can be accessed using reflection, or some sort of properties specific to YAML or Unity?

Comment: I just realized that my question didn't state explicitly that it's an issue with the YamlDotNet library. .NET properties enumerated (with Type.GetProperties(Public | Instance), and are thus sorted from inherited to base type. YamlDotNet then encapulates the properties into _IPropertyDescriptor_ instances. And short of modifying the lib, I don't see a way to sort them otherwise.

Comment: The reason why TypeInspector does not have access to the underlying property is due to the fact that an implementation does not necessarily return IPropertyDescriptors that represent an actual property. You could have an implementation that returns a field, or think about dynamic objects, etc. What you can probably do, but I can't test it right now, is to add your own implementation of ITypeInspector that sorts the properties, similar to https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/master/YamlDotNet/Serialization/TypeInspectors/ReadablePropertiesTypeInspector.cs

Comment: I though about it, but the way the whole typeInspector chain is created (by adding a typeInspectorFactory on the SerializerBuilder), you can either add a typeInspector at the head of the chain, or throw away the entire chain and return something new. In the latter case, I could recreate the chain myself, but it means I must know what are the default TypeInspectors that the SerializerBuilder uses (which is dirty and unsafe).

Comment: @Antoine In my opinion, adding a DeclaringType on the IPropertyDescriptor would the best solution. As you said a IPropertyDescriptor could in fact be a field, a method or any anything else ... but it has to be defined in a class. The DeclaringType would thus always have some meaning.